# Groovy findFiles doesn't find .info files

Tags: file, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

```
f = findFiles(glob: '**xml')
f.each { cov_file->
    println cov_file
}
```

The above code lists xml file whereas fails to print **.info* lcov files when I use ***info*. The xml and info are in the same directory(current directory and also in sub dirs). The above steps are configured in a jenkins pipeline script. jenkins version - *2.346.3*

Comment: "The above code lists xml file whereas fails to print *.info lcov files." - That sounds right to me.  I think `findFiles(glob: '**xml')` is only supposed to select files that have a name that matches the pattern `**xml`.  I am not setup to test different regex in a Jenkins environment but you may want to look at an expression like `.*\\.(xml|info)$`.

Comment: I may need to edit my question. I tried both `**info` and `.*\\.(xml|info)` still no output.

Comment: It is surprising that `**info` selected xml and not info files.  I am sorry that I can't help.  Best of luck!

Comment: sorry if I my explanation is unclear. My point is `**xml` selected xml files whereas `**info` didn't select any files.